# Pos_hint ans size_hint do not seem to work in my kv file and I do not know why

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

So, I've been trying some Kivy, and I've introduced just a button in my kv file associated with the following python code:

```
#importing library
import kivy
kivy.require('1.11.1') #version

#importing functionality
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

class FloatLayout(Widget):
    username = ObjectProperty(None)
    password = ObjectProperty(None)
    """idle code here, does nothing"""

class howyoudoin(App):
    def build(self):
        return FloatLayout()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    howyoudoin().run()
```

And here is my kv file:

```
<Button>:
    font_size:27
    size_hint: 1.0, 1.0
    background_color: 0.1, 0.5, 0.6, 1

<FloatLayout>:
    Button:
        pos_hint:{"top":1.0}
        id: btn
        text: "button"
```

Somehow, the size_hint ans pos_hint commands just won't work for me. This returns my button, but ignoring the pos_hint and size_hint commands.

[The button does not represent the desired position and size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fprS.png)

All other attributes do work: when I change font_size in the code, the font_size changes in the run as well. I can't figure out why :(

Answer (score 0):

You are redefining an existing class (`FloatLayout`), and by doing so you are making it a simple `Widget` as opposed to a `Layout`. Since your `FloayLayout` is not a `Layout`, it does not respect `size_hint` and `pos_hint`. Redefining an existing class is generally a bad idea. If you want to extend `FloatLayout`, try something like this:

```
#importing library
import kivy

kivy.require('1.11.1') #version

#importing functionality
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty


class MyFloatLayout(FloatLayout):
    username = ObjectProperty(None)
    password = ObjectProperty(None)
    """idle code here, does nothing"""


class howyoudoin(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyFloatLayout()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    howyoudoin().run()
```

`kv` file:

```
<Button>:
    font_size:27
    size_hint: 1.0, 1.0
    background_color: 0.1, 0.5, 0.6, 1

<MyFloatLayout>:
    Button:
        pos_hint:{"top":1.0}
        id: btn
        text: "button"
```

In the above code `MyFloatLayout` extends `FloatLayout`, so the `size_hint` and `pos_hint` of the `Button` will now be honored.